# iOS thread error when reading from a text file

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsarray, text-files, sigabrt

I'm trying to print an individual element of an array from a text file, here is the code I'm using :

```
//Tells the compiler where the text file is and its type
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shakes" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];


//This string stores the actual content of the file
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];


//This array holds each word separated by a space as an element 
NSArray *array = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];



//Fast enumeration for loop tha prints out the whole file word by word
// for (NSString* word in array) NSLog(@"%@",word);


//To access a certain element in an array
NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:3
              ]);
```

The problem is - if I wish to access the first 2 elements, 0 or 1, that is fine. However, as soon as I wish to access say, element 2 or 3 I get the following error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
```

It is a SIGABRT threading error - something which seems to crop a lot in iOS programming, but it's normally quite solvable.

The text file "Shakes.txt" is 6 elements long and is only really for testing purposes.

PS - The third line is commented out just incase I want to use it later... So don't worry about that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to access an object which is out of bounds of the array.
The log is very obvious your array only has 1 element and you are trying to access the 4th one.

Add this to your code.

```
   NSMutableArray *contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for (NSString* word in array)
   {
    [contentArray addObject:word]
   }

   //Now try to access contentArray

   NSLog(@"%@", [contentArray objectAtIndex:3
          ]);
```

Comment: I am aware of this, it actually allows me to access 2 elements of the array - 0 and 1. Not sure how to solve it though - as the array in the text file has 6 elements.

Comment: If so then your content is not getting the elements from your text file properly have you tried NSLogging your content?

Comment: Yeah, the third bit of code - the one I've commented out prints the array just fine, all elements.

Comment: The commented for loop just prints the NSStrings in your array it doesn't assure that there are 6 objects in your array.

Comment: It does. I assumed if it printed them it would assure that the 6 objects were in the array. What would you advise to remedy this?

Comment: Just getting the same error when I want to access an element > 1.

Comment: Obviously something wrong with your way of getting the data from your txt file.

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative way to do this?